# I need to push more than one page from main into my flutter app

Tags: flutter

I need more than one page to be pushed at boot time. In main, therefore, "homepage: *screen class name*" is not good. I have to carry out this procedure also later, outside the main. But I read that in this case you can use two or more Navigator.push

Comment: You can load two and present one. What is your target platform? Can you provide some-code that will reproduce the issue?

Comment: It is for android / ios. This is a three-screen registration process. When a user closes the application before finishing the process, as soon as the application is restarted, the last screen the user went to is shown and not the first page. However, I still want the previous pages to be behind the current one in the stack. I am using FirebaseAuth.
I don't think you need my current code because it's a normal main with "homepage: const FirstPage ()"